# Handlebars - Concat string parameters when calling partial

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I would like to know if it is possible to concat a variable with another string when loading a partial using Handlebars.

```
{{partial logos this ns=../ns nsr=../nsr id=id+"something"}}
```

I'd like to concat `id+"something"` and storing it into `id`, which would be sent to the template.

*I'm using a custom helper to load partials (`partial`) which merge `this` with the `options.hash` provided by handlebars.*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a way actually. I've tried with default partial loader ">", but I hope it should work with "partial" too.

You can write a helper like this

```
Handlebars.registerHelper( 'concat', function(path) {
    return "/etc/path" + path;
});
```

and Call it like

```
{{> responsive-image src=(concat '/img/item-tire.png') alt="logo" }}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Still you need to use a helper function but that does the work. Thanks for that hint with parenthesis!

Comment: Hi @Hasanavi, How should I register the helper if I am using Server Side rendering?

Answer (score 15):

Here's an easier way. A helper named 'concat':

```
module.exports = function(){
  var arg = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0);
  arg.pop();
  return arg.join('');
};
```

To be used as:

```
{{>myPartial id=(concat "foo" myVar myOtherVar)}}
```

Comment: Here's an ES6 version: `(...args) => args.slice(0, -1).join('')`

Comment: Much better than my answer +1

Answer (score 5):

You could do a slightly more reusable solution like so:

```
module.exports = function (json) {
  var concat = '';
  var flipArray = [];
  for(var key in json.hash){
    flipArray.push(json.hash[key]);
  }

  for(var i = (flipArray.length - 1); i >= 0; i--){
    concat += flipArray[i];
  }

  return concat;
};
```

Then call it like so:

```
{{> icon name=(concat a="file-" b="pdf")}} // passes file-pdf to the partial under the hash value name
```

or

```
{{concat a="icon-" b="pdf" c="-Asdfasd" d="zxcvzxcvzxcvxz"}} // outputs icon-pdf-Asdfasdzxcvzxcvzxcvxz
```

The reason for the looping backwards in the helper is because handlebars currently lists it's hash parameters from last to first from the order you declare them.

Comment: Interesting. But I don't understand why you're using `module.exports` instead of handlebars helper, that mean you need to load the file somehow.

Comment: Ahh sorry, i'm using pre-compiled grunt handlebars (https://github.com/patrickkettner/grunt-compile-handlebars) which works the same way but processes ur handlebars offline then creates static html for the output. I assume it works the same way for handlebars handled client side, the parameter json might be slightly different but the idea will be the same. Oh and the helper name comes directly from the filename when doing it that way, incase ur where confused, so concat.js has the above code.

Answer (score 3):

Try following. Link helper is my own helper for adding context path **/us**

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('link', function(option,parameter) {
            return '/us' + option.hash.target;
        });

Handlebars.registerHelper('concat', function() {
            var outStr = '';
            for(var arg in arguments){
                if(typeof arguments[arg]!='object'){
                    outStr += arguments[arg];
                }
            }
            return outStr;
        });
```

Then I have called like this. My **url** having **puppies**

```
{{link target=(concat '/' url)}}
```

Then finally i got output like this **/us/puppies**

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. Use concatenation inside your helper.

```
{{partial logos this ns=../ns nsr=../nsr idKey=id idValue="something"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

In ES6 this is possible using this helper:
`concat : (...strs) => strs.join('')`

You may also want to skip parameters given by Handlebars, which is:
`concat : (...strs) => strs.filter( arg => typeof arg !== 'object' ).join('')`

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing a simple `a + b` concatenation and you're already including [handlebars-helpers](https://github.com/helpers/handlebars-helpers), you can use the `add` helper:

```
{{> myPartial myVariable=(add someVariable "some string") }}
```