# Passing handlebars variable as parameter to partial

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I have a partial that render a button like this:

```
{{>button classes="getting-started-button" icon="icon-rocket" text="Getting stared"}}
```

The problem is that the string i want to pass in text="Getting stared" is in itself a handlebars variable that looks like this

```
phrases.getting_started
```

If I add the to the partial call it should look something like this, but it doesn't work

```
{{>button classes="getting-started-button" icon="icon-rocket" text="{{phrases.getting_started}}"}}
```

So how do I solve this?

The partial looks like this:

```
<a 
    class="button {{classes}}" 
    href="{{#if href}}{{href}}{{else}}javascript:{{/if}}" {{#if btn-title}}title="{{btn-title}}"{{/if}}>
    <div class="button-inner">
        {{#if image}}
            <img src="{{image}}" alt="">
        {{else}}
            {{#if icon}}<i class="{{icon}}"></i><span>{{/if}}{{#if text}}{{text}}</span>{{/if}}
        {{/if}}
    </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is even simpler than you thought:

```
{{>button classes="getting-started-button" icon="icon-rocket" text=phrases.getting_started}}
```

Comment: Is there any way to concatenate that variable with a string, e.g.

`{{ button classes="getting-started-button" icon="icon-rocket" text='Some string'+phrases.getting_started }}`

(Does not work)

Thanks

Comment: In handlebars, there is no builtin command for concat, you need to write your own helper, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36963327/8618202